# Change desktop wallpaper from terminal

Tags: linux-mint, desktop, cinnamon

I am running Mint 13 with Cinnamon 1.6. I would like my desktop wallpaper to automatically change depending on the time of day. So, the first thing that comes to mind is setting up a cron job to do it for me. Problem is, I don't know how to change the wallpaper from script / terminal.

What I would like to know:
1) How would one change the background from terminal?
2) Is the there already a built-in way of doing this?

Comment: What's your DE?

Comment: @warl0ck - Cinnamon 1.6

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is the correct answer to the question. Anything else would just be a hack

```
 gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-uri  "file:///filename"
```

Answer (score 11):

With Linux Mint 16 (not sure about other versions) you can use `gsettings` to both *get* information about your current wallpaper as well as *set* it.

The `man gsettings` is a little thin, but TAB completion will work at most steps in the following commands.

Get info:

```
gsettings get org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-uri
gsettings get org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-opacity
gsettings get org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-options
```

To change any option, simply change "get" to "set" and add the new value to the end.

Here is a quick script that will cycle over a known list of wallpapers:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Set the wallpaper from a list
#
# The list, all can be found in $BASE
BASE="file:///home/tigger/.wallpapers/"
LIST="shot1.png another.png just_no_space_in_name.png keep_adding.png"

# The current wallpaper
current=`gsettings get org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-uri`
opacity=`gsettings get org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-opacity`
options=`gsettings get org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-options`

# loop over the list until we find a match
matched=0
new=""
for wp in $LIST
do
    if [ $matched -eq 1 ]
    then
        new="${BASE}${wp}"
        break
    elif [ "'${BASE}${wp}'" = "${current}" ]
    then
        matched=1
    fi
done

# if "$new" is blank, then we show the first shot
if [ "$new" = "" ]
then
    new=${BASE}${LIST%% *}
fi

# set the wallpaper
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-uri \'${new}\'
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-opacity ${opacity}
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-options ${options}
```

Answer (score 4):

In terms of the x window system you want to change the background of the root window.  The "builtin"-tool to change the settings of this window is `xsetroot`. Unfortunately it's a bit outdated, for instance it only supports to choose bitmaps for the background-image.

I prefer the tool `hsetroot` over `xsetroot`. Both tools must be used from the command line.

Moreover I can imagine that you can adjust settings of the root window via the x resource database but i can't find related informations by now.

Comment: hsetroot seems to be exactly what I want, but it's not setting my desktop background; instead, it sets the background of the workspaces selection when I hover over the hot corner. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Works for me on Linuxmint 13 with Cinnamon 1.4.

- `cinnamon-settings desktop` # in terminal > Untick "Let file manager handle the desktop"
- change your wallpaper with feh

  ```
  feh --bg-fill ~/Images/my_wallpaper.png
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
xsetbg /path/to/wallpaper.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not affect the wallpaper. It does however change the screen shown when logging out. I'm starting to think that Cinnamon treats x11 settings in a different way than other environments do.

Comment: @user1166877: Wierd, it works for me. I've used Metacity and Openbox as window managers, but I think this is "below" that. Check out precisely what I [use](http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/sys.txt) if that could offer a clue as to what differs.

Answer (score 1):

There is something called [DesktopNova](https://launchpad.net/desktopnova).